# How to Provision Bundle committed through HTTP API in Apache Ace

Tags: apache, repository, bundle, target, apache-ace

I am committing a bundle(say Test.jar) to the Apache Ace Repository using the HTTP API, `http://<Ace Host>/repository/commit?customer=apache&name=shop&version=2`. After this how can i provision this bundle to a target?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit puzzled by your question because the repository you mention contains metadata (in XML format) that describes the relationship between artifacts (bundles or other files), features and distributions. You should not commit bundles to it. Bundles go in the OBR, which has its own REST API if you programmatically want to upload them.

To provision a bundle to a target, using the Web UI, you:

1. Upload the bundle as a new artifact. It will be sent to the OBR and show up in the artifacts column.
2. Associate the artifact with a feature and the feature with a distribution.
3. Launch an new target and watch it show up in the UI (you might need to "retrieve" the current configuration for that to happen).
4. Associate the distribution with the target.
5. Commit everything.